# Random selection team member from chatbot and start the conversation

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot

I created **PVA chatbot** in **Teams**, which should help us in realization of daily scrum meeting. Except standard features like make questions, one feature of bot should be random **selecting team member in chat**, who starts the conversation (or answers on the questions). Is there any idea how to implement this feature in chatbot? Is it possible that chatbot discovers which members of teams are present and randomly selects one of the team member ?

Comment: Please check [Fetch the roster or user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#fetch-the-roster-or-user-profile) to get the list of members in a team.

Comment: Then you can write a custom logic to randomly select a user from the list of members. For example

       public static void Main()
        {
                var usersList = "ABC, DEF, GHI";
                // Randomize original array. 
                Random rnd = new Random();
                var user = usersList.Split(',').ToArray().OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).FirstOrDefault(); 
                Console.WriteLine(user);
        }